AREI-symbols in LaTeX
I was wondering if anyone ever made symbols for an electrical installation (or is there a package?), single-pole switch, dual pole switches, fuses, etc...


circuitikz? I am not sure it has all or any of the ones you need but seems related

Every now and then, this question comes up. I am unsure actually whether there exists already a package for these. Do you happen to have an exhaustive list? I wonder whether it would be reasonable to include them in circuitikz, as they are also used isolated (on construction plans for example), if I am not mistaken. Maybe a TikZ library would be a good idea? There is already this library, but it also does not cover all of these ...
